# How to extend Playwrights test method to take storage path?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have multiple user types e.g. non-premium, standard, premium. I want to test each with preauthorisation. I previously used describe blocks and `test.use({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/admin.json' });` so I can have the tests in the same file. But this isn't as clean as I'd like.

Ideally I'd love to have an extension to do something like the following, where it would close the contexts/browsers automatically. There does seem to be an extend functionality, but not in the way I'd like.

```js
test('Example 1', storage: 'file.json', async ({ page }) => {
   // ...
});
```

But this is what I currently have:

```js
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test('Example 1', async ({ browser }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user-type-1.json' });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    
    // ...

    await context.close();
});

test('Example 2', async ({ browser }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user-type-2.json' });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    
    // ...

    await context.close();
});
```

The docs suggest something similar for multiple contexts, which makes sense, but I only have a single context so it's a bit messy to always create and close a context. There doesn't seem like another way to create a test with the context otherwise.